# Function not running everytime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I learn by creating a simple game, something like space invaders. And the problem that i have is sometimes a script is executed and sometimes its not. Let me show you the code:

First my player fires a gun, it instantiates a prefab of bullet.

Fire a gun:

```
void Update() { 
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) { 
        Instantiate(rocket, strzal.position, strzal.rotation); 
    } 
}
```

Bullet script:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) { 
   if (collision.gameObject.tag== "Przeszkoda"){ 
       collision.GetComponent().TakeDamage(damage); 
       Destroy(gameObject); 
   } 
}
```

Then if the bullet hits a target it triggers a damage function:

```
public void TakeDamage(float amount) { 
   health -= amount; 
   if (health <= 0) { 
       ABC.GetComponent<DEF>().NowyPoziomTrudnosci(); 
       gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

And so far everything is working just fine. But problem starts with `NowyPoziomTrudnosci` function. Sometimes its running then 3 enemies are killed and nothing happens and 2 next enemies run the code and again x enemies die and code is not executing.

```
public void NowyPoziomTrudnosci() { 
    kills = kills + 1; 
    Debug.Log("wykonane"+ kills); 
}
```

Any idea where I made a mistake? I would understand if `NowyPoziomTrudnosci` wouldn't run at all. But it's running, just not every time.

Comment: Either `TakeDamage` is not being called, or `health` is not <= 0. Have you stepped through the code? That should show you why the line isn't executing.

Comment: I suspect something about that gameObject.SetActive(false);. What happen if you comment it for a test?

Comment: Maybe I am blind, but what is ABC in this code? Also, an overloaded method of `GetComponent()` does not exist, this code seems incomplete to me. What components are you trying to retrieve with `GetComponent()`?

Comment: @Maxplay ABC is my gamemanager object. I wanted it to store data about killed enemies and when there is enough enemies killed to increase the difficulty of the game. Code of ABC goes like this:
    public class DEF : MonoBehaviour {

    public float poziomTrudnosci = 1;
    private float kills = 0; 
    public void NowyPoziomTrudnosci()
    {
        kills = kills + 1;
        Debug.Log("wykonane"+ kills);
        }}

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is `ABC` a `GameObject`? There's no `gameObject.GetComponent()` method (*with no arguments*) defined in the Unity API. Are you sure that you wrote the code correctly here? As written, it looks like it shouldn't even compile successfully.

Comment: @Ruzihm Thank you for your answer. I fixed the part with no argument in GetComponent method, but the function still runs at random :( Now its:
ABC.GetComponent<DEF>().NowyPoziomTrudnosci(); 
I'm totally confused.

Comment: Does your code log any errors or exceptions when you kill an enemy? Something might be null sometimes and failing to reach that code.

Comment: @Ruzihm 0 errors 0 exceptions, I can't paste whole code here and I dont think spamming is a good way to go so maybe you can look at the project itself? It's really small, I uploaded it here: https:// we .tl/t-ekO5gjrlGJ

Comment: Are your colliders (particularly the moving ones) set as Continuous or Discrete?

Comment: Did you try to set breakpoints and debug your code? `collision.GetComponent()` still has no parameters ...